# facebook October changes - send dialog with metadata

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using JS SDK for the send dialog:

```
FB.ui({
    app_id: appId,
    method: 'send',
    link: window.location.protocol+'//'+server+'/xxxxx',
            name: 'name',
    description: 'description',
    to: '1111111111'
    });
```

The 'name' and 'description' parameters are ignored.
I understood that using metadata tags is the solution.
What tags should I use for the name and description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The metadata tags are called Open Graph tags. There are many of types data that can be included in these headers, if you are curious then read up about the options [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/) and [here](http://ogp.me/).

To specify just the name and the description, you should use the og:title and og:description tags in the HTML of the URL being sent, like this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Name Goes Here" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Some text about this link goes here" />
```

One thing to remember is that Facebook caches this data quite aggressively - so you might find yourself wondering why when you've changed the tag, the text in the send dialog is not changing. If this happens, paste the URL into Facebook's Object Debugger - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and it should clear their cached version.